# When using Twilio iOS sdk and building Cordova app openssl crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, openssl, twilio

I am building a cordova app for iOS and I am using Twilio Plugin with the corresponding [Twilio iOS SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=stackdocsupdate). 
For some reason, after calling the setup method from Twilio plugin ( which then calls native code ), the app crashes.
Here is the link of stack trace:

[image]

The exception I get is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I know that the problem may not be in cordova because i downloaded phonekit app and it does not crashes.
https://github.com/jconst/PhoneKit

This is cordova plugin I am using:

The method I call is : `Twilio.Device.setup`

From there, it will execute native code which is in TCPlugin.

jefflinwood - twilio_client_phonegap

I would appreciate any insight on the topic.

Unfortunately, I am still struggling with how to make both sdks work together. I am contacting opentok support to see if the can help.

(EDITED)

Comment: That's a call stack, not a stack trace. You need to provide more information, like where the crash is located and what the parameters are. ***`bt full`*** used to work with GDB, but I'm not sure if LLDB takes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just remove libssl references from project. That way, twilio will use opentok openssl libraries.
In my case, I delete libssl from twilio folder. I was using xCode and was not that simple to exclude it from project, since There is "search libraries path" which looks for all libraries.
Then if you are using Pods, make sure to do not use Pods.config, because it will also look for libssl library.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved. Here is what was going on. I was using OpenTok plugin as well in my project. OpenTok also uses openssl which conflicts with the one used by twilio ( differente version).
I partialy solved this by removing openTok. Eventually Ill need to find a way to use both plugins.

Comment: I am having same issue like you have with openTok. How u manage to fix it. How u modified the code to use both plugins..