# Cannot Register SIP with Twilio SDK

Tags: android, ios, cordova, twilio, sip

I've been struggling trying to integrate Twilio SDK to my cordova app.
When I call Twilio.Device.Setup with capability token, I receive this log:

2015-06-24 17:12:03.000[239:26713] PJSIP(2):    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration failed, status=302 (Moved Temporarily)

2015-06-24 17:12:03.005[239:26713] PJSIP(1):    pjsua_acc.c  .....Unable to create/send REGISTER: Object is busy (PJSIP_EBUSY) [status=171001]

2015-06-24 17:12:03.752[239:26528] State: Offline

What could have been causing this issue? 
I am willing to provide any information.

UPDATE/SOLUTION:

I am providing my solution here.

The problem was because the capability token was generated wrong. So I would check out that immediately. 
`capability = TwilioCapability(account_sid, auth_token) capability.allow_client_outgoing(application_sid) print capability.generate()`

I also had a problem with the twilio cordova plugin. Twilio changed the sdk so this was causing an issue on the plugin. They have already make a fix for the plugin so try to keep it updated.

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Comment: Yes, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012159/when-using-twilio-ios-sdk-and-building-cordova-app-openssl-crashes

Comment: I'm an android developer so please explain me in brief.

Comment: The problem was because the capability token was generated wrong. So I would check out that immediately. 
`capability = TwilioCapability(account_sid, auth_token)
capability.allow_client_outgoing(application_sid)
print capability.generate()`

Comment: token is generating correctly ......tested with with postman , but still problem is coming when making request from android app ,

Comment: I also had a problem with the twilio cordova plugin. Twilio changed the sdk so this was causing an issue on the plugin. They have already make a fix for the plugin so try to keep it updated.

Comment: @FedericoMartinez, would you mind updating this question with the answer you found? It will be most helpful for the community in that format.